# Integration between IBM MQ Series and ActiveMQ Artemis at enterprise level

Tags: activemq-artemis

We are currently using IBM MQ for messaging and moving to ActiveMQ, but the challenge is there are few producers who would continue to use IBM MQ for sometime whereas consumers are ready to migrate.

Is there a way we can bridge IBM MQ and ActiveMQ Artemis, so that any message that arrives in IBM MQ queue should get auto replicated in ActiveMQ and consumer pick up from there ( same goes in reverse order)?

Implementing a new service which consume from IBM MQ and put of ActiveMQ does not seem feasible as there are huge list of services and this redundant work does not seems feasible at enterprise level.

Comment: Your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120994/message-exchange-between-ibm-mq-to-activemq-artemis) just like this was already closed as a duplicate. You at least need to explain why the answer in the duplicate doesn't work for you otherwise this one will be closed for the same reason. What specifically do you mean by "implementing a new service"?

Comment: @JustinBertram - honetsly speaking, I am not quite getting on that and if its JMS based implementation like building new service which consumer from IBM MQ and publish to ActiveMQ.. this is not what we are trying.. just asking, do we have anywhere step by step guid officially or some blogs which can help in detail

Comment: I don't really understand your last comment. You asked how you can "bridge" messages from IBM MQ  and ActiveMQ Artemis. How is it possible to accomplish this *without* consuming messages from one broker and sending them to the other? Also, you don't need to build any "new service". You just need to configure services that *already exist*.